# Send data from Web application to windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, rest, wcf

Are their any way to send data or request from web application written in asp.net c#
to window forms application and receive the response at server side?

Comment: you could use REST or WCF to send requests to your web application. if you could add more about what you're trying to accomplish, it might be easier for other to help you come up with a solution.

Comment: As it stands, I cant make sense of the question, you send from asp.net application to windows forms? and somehow the response ends at the server? Why not just send strait to the server instead of the form? also what type of communication do you expect from the windows forms to aspnet app?

Comment: I've developed web app that can access client resources i.e: scanner or printer, using selverlight, but now I need to do this without using selverlight.

Comment: From the web side you need to reference the System.Management namespace. Everything you need to determine printers etc you should be able to get via this